# BERT Heads Count

Tags: bert-language-model, transformer-model

From the literature I read,

Bert Base has 12 encoder layers and 12 attention heads.  Bert Large has 24 encoder layers and 16 attention heads.

Why is Bert large having 16 attentions heads ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of attention heads is irrespective of the number of (encoder) layers.
However, there is an inherent tie between the hidden size of each model (768 for `bert-base`, and 1024 for `bert-large`), which is explained in [the original Transformers paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf).
Essentially, the choice made by the authors is that the self-attention block size (`d_k`) equals the hidden dimension (`d_hidden`), divided by the number of heads (`h`), or formally

```
d_k = d_hidden / h
```

Since the standard choice seems to be `d_k = 64`, we can infer the final size from our parameters:

```
h = d_hidden / d_k = 1024 / 64 = 16
```

which is exactly the value you are looking at in `bert-large`.

Comment: Thanks.  I went to re-read the paper again and can't seem to find the formula.  Is this "intuitively" derived ?

Comment: It is mentioned at the very end of section 3.2.2; the choice of `d_k` is explained throughout this chapter.